# Add a ActiveX Control to a JPanel

Tags: java, activex

Is there any way to add a ActiveX control to a JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily?  No.

With a bridging technology *(which in my opinion are to be avoided)*?  Yea, with something like **[Bridge2Java](http://jcay.org/java/applications/development-tools/bridge2java.html)**.

> Bridge2Java is a tool that allows Java
>   programs to communicate with ActiveX
>   objects. It allows easy integration of
>   ActiveX objects into a Java
>   Environment. Using the Java Native
>   Interface and COM technology,
>   Bridge2Java allows an ActiveX object
>   to be treated just like a Java object.

Answer (score 0):

I am also suggest the Bridge2Java, it is a cool tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the Jacob library, which you can use via groovy if you're interested:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/
- http://groovy.codehaus.org/COM+Scripting